# Is it possible to emulate MySQL replication SlaveIO and SlaveSQL crashing to test monitoring script?

Tags: mysql, database-replication

We have a MySQL setup running a single master and two replication slaves. We recently ran into a scenario where SlaveIO had stopped on one of the replication slaves and SlaveSQL had stopped on the other replication slave. This had silently stopped replication on both slave servers.

I decided to write a monitoring plugin for Nagios to keep an eye on the status of SlaveIO and SlaveSQL. The problem I am having is emulating the scenarios we ran into above. I can issue a "STOP SLAVE" command to stop both SlaveIO and SlaveSQL, but I would like to stop each individually to be sure the script reacts correctly.

Is this possible?

Comment: Connect to the slaves directly and issue the stop replication commands there instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  `SLAVE STOP SQL_THREAD` and `SLAVE STOP IO_THREAD`

See [“Pausing Replication on the Slave”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-administration-pausing.html) in the MySQL manual.

Comment: I didn't notice that section in the online manual. Worked great, thank you!